# Wordpress Magic Fields 2 - Getting duplicate fields - get_field_duplicate() undefined?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress Magic Fields and have a post type with a field for file attachments/uploads. This field is able to be duplicated so the client can upload multiple files.

I am trying to retrieve the value of each of these duplicate fields and it isn't working. The recommended function [according to the wiki](http://wiki.magicfields.org/doku.php?id=dealing_with_groups_duplicate_groups_and_duplicate_fields#duplicate_fields)

```
get_field_duplicate
```

Is supposedly undefined.

```
Call to undefined function get_field_duplicate()
```

I'm not finding any other documentation online, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Magic Fields 2 **get_field_duplicate** doesn't exist, you can use **get_field.**

```
 <?php 
     $value  = get_field ('movie') ;
       foreach ( $value  as  $my_val ) { 
       echo $my_val;
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: How can I use this with images ?  I've tried breaking out of the php and throwing an img tag around the echo but haven't pulled it off yet.